# Binding dyanmic data to DropdownBox in SAPUI5 table

Tags: sapui5

I want to bind the dynamic Dropdowns for each row in SAPUI5 table. There should be the row-specific data for each row-Dropdown. Here is the sample json having three rows. But I'm unable to bind the row-specific data for each dropdown. Thanks in Advance!

**Here, I have simple table.**

```
    // Table goes here
    var demoTbl = new sap.ui.table.Table({
        visibleRowCount: 10,
        width : "100%",
        selectionMode: sap.ui.table.SelectionMode.Multi,
    });

    var systemColumn = new sap.ui.table.Column({
        width:"12%",
        label: new sap.ui.commons.Label({text: "System", design:sap.ui.commons.LabelDesign.Bold}),
        template: new sap.ui.commons.TextField({editable:false}).bindProperty("value", "name"),
        sortProperty: "name",  
        filterProperty: "name",
        sorted : false,
        filtered : false
    });
    demoTbl.addColumn(systemColumn);
```

> bind list data for 1st row-Dropdown List here-

```
    var inputListBox = new sap.ui.commons.ListBox();
    inputListBox.bindAggregation("items","/listData/dataList/0/dropList",function(oId,oContext){
        console.log(oContext);
        return new sap.ui.core.ListItem({
            key: oContext.getProperty("id"),
            text: oContext.getProperty("name")
        });
    });

    var connectorIpColumn = new sap.ui.table.Column({
        width:"12%",
        label: new sap.ui.commons.Label({text: "Dropdown Data", design:sap.ui.commons.LabelDesign.Bold}),
        template: new sap.ui.commons.DropdownBox({
            "association:listBox" : inputListBox
        })
    });
    demoTbl.addColumn(connectorIpColumn);
```

**And, here is the Data -**

```
    var oData={
    "dataList": [{
             "id": 111,
             "name": "Row1 Data",
             "dropList": [
                 {"id": 1, "name": "Row1 dropDown Item1"},
                 {"id": 2, "name": "Row1 dropDown Item2"},
                 {"id": 3, "name": "Row1 dropDown Item3"},
                 {"id": 4, "name": "Row1 dropDown Item4"}
             ]
         },
         {
             "id": 222,
             "name": "Row2 Data",
             "dropList": [
                 {"id": 5, "name": "Row2 dropDown Item1"},
                 {"id": 6, "name": "Row2 dropDown Item2"},
                 {"id": 7, "name": "Row2 dropDown Item3"}
             ]
         },
         {
             "id": 333,
             "name": "Row3 Data",
             "dropList": [
                 {"id": 8, "name": "Row3 dropDown Item1"},
                 {"id": 9, "name": "Row3 dropDown Item2"},
                 {"id": 10, "name": "Row3 dropDown Item3"}
             ]
         }
     ]};
```

**Bind data here-**

```
    var mappingModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel({listData:oData});
    sap.ui.getCore().setModel(mappingModel, "mappingModel");
    demoTbl.setModel(mappingModel);
    demoTbl.bindRows("/listData/dataList");
    mappingModel.refresh(true);

    var addSystemPage =  new sap.m.Page( {
        content:[demoTbl]
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to provide the aggregation binding path for ListBox template as 'dropList'.

```
inputListBox.bindAggregation("items","dropList",function(oId,oContext){
        return new sap.ui.core.ListItem({
            key: oContext.getProperty("id"),
            text: oContext.getProperty("name")
        });
});
```

Comment: Please close the question then.